# Hadoop: less shuffletime does not show in cpu time

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

When running our MapReduce program on Hadoop, we observed that the some reducers had a large shuffle time. We concluded that this happened because the required map containers exceeded the available containers on the cluster. This caused the reducers to 'block' in their shuffle phase until all mappers were done. The reducers that do not depict this behaviour were probably started *after* all mappers completed. The effect can be seen in the first image below.

We then disabled the slowstart by setting `mapreduce.job.reduce.slowstart.completedmaps` to `1`. This resulted in a much lower shuffle time, confirming our hypothesis. The result can be seen in the second image below.

One would now expect to see a much lower cpu time for the second job. Strangely, this is not the case. The CPU time is exactly the same. One reason could be that some things are not counted by the shuffle, merge and reduce timers.

What could cause this mismatch between the total measured map and reduce (elapsed) times and the total cpu milliseconds?

Additional Question: what could cause the mappers in the second job to behave so different as they do in the first job?

Thanks for your insights.

[image: Reducers wait for a long time]
[image]